# Is OSI model merely used for troubleshooting purpose?

Tags: tcp, osi

I'm a student and recently started understanding OSI model, from what I understand is that OSI model is just theoretical and not really used in real world. It's mainly for troubleshooting purpose.

I've got two questions here

1. What do we use in real world then? My assumption is TCP/IP?
2. Why can't we use TCP/IP for troubleshooting as well if we can use OSI model?

Comment: For first question, you mentioned that TCP/IP is closer to what currently is used, what about the second question? Can we troubleshoot with TCP/IP too, if yes then why do we need OSI when we can get things done with TCP/IP alone?

Comment: As the linked question explains, both models are nearly identical at the lower layers, so you can use either one.  As to why OSI is still being taught even though nothing in use today is based on it, is admittedly a bit of a mystery to me.  I guess old habits die hard.

Comment: I'm not even a CS student, just wanted to understand how things work and browsing on the internet all I get is OSI model so I tried understanding it which made me curious to understand why do people talk about it all the time.

Comment: I read first few paragraphs of your answer and you mentioned that it was never used because TCP/IP came up which was free so the industry kind of shifted towards it, which makes me wonder how come even after decades we are talking about something which was never implemented.

Comment: The real point about teaching OSI or TCPIP models is to understand the concept of layers. Where you draw the line between them or how many you have is not that important.